# SQL: Getting values which all other values related to each must be in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I'm working in a web page with PHP and MySQL where I have this DB:

```sql
CREATE TABLE action (
  idaction INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  --Other columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`idaction`));

CREATE event (
  idevent INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  --Other columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`idevent`));

CREATE TABLE currentGame (
  user_email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  --Other columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_email`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currentEvents (
  currentGame_user_email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  event_idevent INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (currentGame_user_email, event_idevent),
  FOREIGN KEY (currentGame_user_email) REFERENCES currentGame (user_email),
  FOREIGN KEY (event_idevent) REFERENCES event (idevent));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spawnConditions (
  action_idaction INT NOT NULL,
  event_idevent INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (action_idaction, event_idevent),
  FOREIGN KEY (action_idaction) REFERENCES action (idaction),
  FOREIGN KEY (event_idevent) REFERENCES event (idevent));
```

So I need to do a query which has the actions which fulfill any of these conditions:

1. It is not in `spawnConditions`.
2. If it is in `spawnConditions`, all the events which it is related to in this table, must be in the subgroup of `currentEvent` with a certain known `user_email`.

In other words, for action A1, being in `spawnConditions` with events E1 and E2, to be able to be selected from table `action`, both E1 and E2 must be in `currentEvents` with the known `currentGame_user_email`.

Can it be written using only SQL or do I need to involve PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `not exists` can get the work done here. Basically, you want to filter out actions for which a corresponding record exists in `currentEvents` with a `currentGame_user_email` other than a fixed value:

```
select a.*
from action a
where not exists (
    select 1
    from spawnConditions sc
    inner join currentEvents ce 
        on ce.event_idevent = sc.event_idevent
    where 
        sc.action_idaction = a.idaction
        and ce.currentGame_user_email <> ?
)
```

The question mark represents the "certain known user_email" you mentioned in the question.

Comment: The 1 you are using is like "LIMIT 1" I supose, right? So would it work fine removing it?

Comment: @PABLOMARTINEZGUILLEN: removing what? `select 1` is an important part of this query, removing it will cause a syntax ereror.

Comment: So I copied your code and after some work I can't get it to work, it just returns all the actions. I slightly changed it to adapt it to my program, the string I have in php for mysqli is:"
  select ".$idGame.", idaction
   from action where not exists (
    select 1
    from spawnConditions sc
     inner join currentEvents ce 
        on ce.event_idevent = sc.event_idevent
    where 
        sc.action_idaction = action.idaction
        and ce.currentGame_user_email <> ".$idGame.")"